# reloadRowsAtIndexPath prevents scrollToRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift

I'm developing a chat application in SWIFT.

---

Whenever the user sends a chat message, it gets added to the dataSource
with the variable

`var sending : Bool = true`

If  the `sending` is set `true`, then the cell displays a little "sending" icon besides the message bubble.

---

**The problem is the following:** `reloadRows()` stops the scrolling

Whenever a message is being sent it gets added to the tableView, and the tableView scrolls down to the new message:

```
self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: dataSource.count-1, section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: true)
```

BUT

Almost immediately the **chat server** responds **whether the sending was successful**.

**If yes**, The chat messages `sending` variable gets set to `false` and the cell gets reloaded:

```
self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .none)
```

---

**The problem is** that the scrolling will not happen, due to the fact that `reloadRows` seems to prevent it. (The height of the row doesn't change, so I don't understand)

---

Currently I'm doing the following to fix that, but there must be an other solution:

If the `tableView` is not scrolling, I simply reload the row.
If it is scrolling, the app waits, it collects all the rows that needs to be reloaded, and does it after `scrollViewDidEndDeclearing`

**Code:**

```
    var reloadRows : [IndexPath] = []
    var isTableViewScrolling : Bool = false
    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView == tableView {
            isTableViewScrolling = true
        }
    }
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        if scrollView == tableView {
            isTableViewScrolling = false

            if reloadRows.count > 0 {
                // Reload the needed rows
                self.tableView.reloadRows(at: reloadRows, with: .none)
                reloadRows = []
            }
        }
    }
    @objc func notification_sentMessageCallback(notification: NSNotification){

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let chatRoomId = notification.userInfo?["chatRoomId"] as? Int, let id = notification.userInfo?["id"] as? Int {

                if (self.currentChatRoomId == chatRoomId){

                    guard let index = ChatStore.shared.chatRoom(id: chatRoomId).messages.index(where: { $0.id! == id }) else {
                        return
                    }

                    if self.isTableViewScrolling {

                        self.reloadRows.append(IndexPath(row: index, section: 0))
                    } else {
                        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .none)

                    }


                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: If reloadRowing without animations, could you directly set the content of cell at indexPath of "index"?